# Get content controls in word header / footer with office interop assemblies

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-pia

I'm writing an application which reads out content controls from word documents. It works fine, but I'm not able to get the controls in the header and footer of the document.

Here's my code:

```
public static List<string> GetContentControlsList(word.Document currentWordDocument)
{
    List<string> contentControlsList = new List<string>();

     try
     {
         ContentControls contentControlsCollection = currentWordDocument.ContentControls;

         if (contentControlsCollection != null)
         {
             if (contentControlsCollection.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (ContentControl contentControl in contentControlsCollection)
                 {
                     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentControl.Title) && !contentControlsList.Contains(contentControl.Title))
                     {
                         contentControlsList.Add(contentControl.Title);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // TODO do error handling here
     }

     return contentControlsList;
 }
```

I am able to get the content controls from text body with this code but I also need header and footer.

Comment: you need to add additional loop which will check in `document.storyranges` where headers and footers belong to. Please keep in mind that there are few types of headers and footers therefore I suggest to use additional loop. Inside each `storyrange` you will find additional `ContentControls` to deal with.

Comment: Thanks, I loop through storyranges and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (code has to be refactored a little bit but I think the principle is clear):

```
    public static List<string> GetContentControlsList(word.Document currentWordDocument)
    {
        List<string> contentControlsList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            ContentControls contentControlsCollection = currentWordDocument.ContentControls;

            if (contentControlsCollection != null)
            {
                if (contentControlsCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (ContentControl contentControl in contentControlsCollection)
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentControl.Title) && !contentControlsList.Contains(contentControl.Title))
                        {
                            contentControlsList.Add(contentControl.Title);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Get storyRanges from document for header and footer properties
            StoryRanges storyRanges = currentWordDocument.StoryRanges;

            foreach (Range storyRange in storyRanges)
            {
                ContentControls storyRangeControls = storyRange.ContentControls;

                if (storyRangeControls != null)
                {
                    if (storyRangeControls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (ContentControl control in storyRangeControls)
                        {
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Title) && !contentControlsList.Contains(control.Title))
                            {
                                contentControlsList.Add(control.Title);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO do error handling here
        }

        return contentControlsList;
    }
```

Thanks to KazJaw for his comment.